Can't fix the mesh grid
I cant seem to get the square geometry of my model back. whenever i add in an edge using control R, the line doesnt show up, and facing vertices off gets rid of the smoothness of the model. I am not sure how to fix

I’m guessing you have a subdivision surface modifier active?

In the Subdivision Modifier, check the 'On Cage' boton right next to the name of the modifier. It will make the geometry curve like the modified object and it will be easier to see what you are doing. Idk about the part that is not visible but you have several faces in there that are not quads. Edge Loops will not cross those faces.
To smooth it out you could try going into sculpt mode, mask the area and use the smooth brush or Mesh Filter tool set to Smooth

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Or make the Subdivision Surface modifier invisible until you're glad with the topology (screen icon button of the modifier)
